# Rails ActiveRecord sort by count of join table associations

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a `Resource` model that can be voted on using the "Acts As Votable" gem ([Github page](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable)). The voting system works perfectly but I am trying to display pages ordered by how many `votes` each `Resource` has.

Currently my controller pulls Resources based on tags and aren't ordered:

```
@resources = Resource.where(language_id: "ruby")
```

If I take an individual resource and call "@resource.votes.size" it will return how many votes it has. However, votes is another table so I think some sort of join needs to be done but I have not sure how to do it. What I need is a nice ordered `ActiveRecord` collection I can display like this?

> Book name - 19 votes
>
> Book name - 15 votes
>
> Book name - 9 votes
>
> Book name - 8 votes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following:

```
@resources = Resouce.select("resources.*, COUNT(votes.id) vote_count")
                    .joins(:votes)
                    .where(language_id: "ruby")
                    .group("resources.id")
                    .order("vote_count DESC")

@resources.each { |r| puts "#{r.whatever}  #{r.vote_count}" }
```

To include resources with 0 votes, use an outer join.  If the example below doesn't work as is you'll have to alter the joins statement to join across the correct relations.

```
@resources = Resource.select("resources.*, COUNT(votes.id) vote_count")
                     .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON votes.votable_id = resources.id AND votes.votable_type = 'Resource'")
                     .where(language_id: "ruby")
                     .group("resources.id")
                     .order("vote_count DESC")
```

Comment: That was close I used this:
@resources = Resource.select("resources.*, COUNT(votes.id) vote_count").joins(:votes).group("resources.id").order("vote_count DESC")

Comment: I get an SQL exception for the outer join

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49183/discussion-between-t-j-and-joel-smith)

Comment: With Rails 5, there's now direct support for left outer joins http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/24/support-for-left-outer-joins-in-rails-5.html

Comment: @TJ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56669484/how-to-get-value-using-join-table-with-different-values/56680298#56680298

Answer (score 5):

## Rails 5+

Built-in support for left outer joins was introduced in `Rails 5` so you can use that to do this. This way you'll still keep the records that have 0 relationships:

```
Resource
  .where(language_id: 'ruby')
  .left_joins(:votes)
  .group(:id)
  .select('resources.*', 'COUNT(votes.id) vote_count')
  .order('vote_count DESC')
```

Answer (score 2):

It would return the resources that have the most votes

```
@resources.joins(:votes).group("resources.id").order("count(resources.id) DESC")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply [Group clause](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group) like this:

```
@resources = Resource.select('resources.*, count(votes.id) as votes_count').
  joins(:votes).group(:id).order('votes_count DESC')
```

Comment: Same problem as the other answer, any resource with zero votes isn't being displayed

Comment: @Joel Smith If you need to display zero votes, try doing LEFT JOIN like `Resource.select('resources.*, count(votes.id) as votes_count').joins('LEFT JOIN votes on resources.id = votes.resource_id').group(:id).order('votes_count DESC')`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the fastest and most painful way to handle it is to use counter cache: Here is a railscast - http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column.

In short - you simply add a column called `<association_name>_count` and add `counter_cache: true` to you association definition. Rails will take care of updating the `<association_name>_count` column so it always shows the number of associated objects.

Warning: it will not pre-populate this column on creation, you need to do this in your migration for all existing parent records.