# Count and Sort on Join table in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have pretty much the same scenario as this post, [Rails ActiveRecord sort by count of join table associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234983/rails-activerecord-sort-by-count-of-join-table-associations/22235146), but I can't quite get it to work.

I have a table called `coffeeshops` where a table of `users` can favorite a coffee shop via a third table called `favorite_coffeeshops`.  I am using the `acts_as_taggable` gem.

```
class Coffeeshop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :favorite_coffeeshops# just the 'relationships'
  has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_coffeeshops, source: :user

class FavoriteCoffeeshop < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :coffeeshop
  belongs_to :user

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :coffeeshops
  has_many :favorite_coffeeshops # just the 'relationships'
  has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_coffeeshops, source: :coffeeshop
```

In my controller I have the following:

```
def index
....

@favshops = Coffeeshop.select
('coffeeshops.*, count(favorite_coffeeshops.coffeeshop_id) as favorite_coffeeshops_count')
.joins(:favorite_coffeeshops.group(:favorite_coffeeshops.coffeeshop_id)
.order('favorite_coffeeshops DESC')
end
```

I'm actually getting a syntax error, before I can even check if the query is right.  Is this to do with wrapping the string across multiple lines?

```
SyntaxError (/Users/Simon/gourmet_coffee/app/controllers/home_controller.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
  end
     ^
/Users/Simon/gourmet_coffee/app/controllers/home_controller.rb:17: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error is telling you that it’s expecting a `)` character to close a parenthesis, but reaching an `end` statement instead.

If you look at this line:

`.joins(:favorite_coffeeshops.group(:favorite_coffeeshops.coffeeshop_id)`

(which should be line 12 according to your syntax error), then you can see that there are two opening `(` characters, but only one closing `)`.

So to fix the syntax error you just need to add the missing `)` for the `joins` method, before the `group` method is called, i.e.:

`.joins(:favorite_coffeeshops).group(:favorite_coffeeshops.coffeeshop_id)`